# I created a post build plugin in jenkins but the entries in config.jelly regarding the text box are not getting reflected in my Plugin UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created a post build plugin in jenkins but the entries in config.jelly regarding the text box are not getting reflected in my Plugin UI. but when change the code of this plugin to Build task plugin , the text fields are now being shown at the UI , infact now I can at, runtime validate the entries in the text box . Any ideas why this is happening .. Please guide